# How is this JS Object modified?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the less than descriptive title, had a hard time summarizing my question in a good way.

My question is basically, how does the code below work?

```
var originalPerson = {
    person: { name: { first: 'John' } }
};

function update(path, val) {
  var pathParts = path.split('.');

  var person = originalPerson;
  var part;

  while (pathParts.length > 1) {
    part = pathParts.shift();
    person[part] = typeof person[part] === 'object' ? person[part] : {};
    person = person[part];
  }

  person[pathParts[0]] = val;
}    

update('person.name.last', 'Doe');
// originalPerson.name is:
// { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' } }
```

I think that I understand the parts. In `update()` `person` is created as a reference to `originalPerson`. Once the `while` loop is complete `originalPerson` seems unaltered, and `person` is `{ first: 'John' }`.

However, after `person[pathParts[0]] = val;`, `originalPerson` is updated and now contains the new property `last` that was passed into the function.

What confuses me is why `originalPerson` is not updated when its reference is. This is the behavior I am expecting:

```
var person = { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' } }
var jane = person;

jane.name.first = 'Jane';
```

In this example, both `jane.name.first` and `person.name.first` are set to 'Jane' after the third row.

Why is the behavior in the first example different?

Answer (score 0):

What the `while` loop in the first example actually does is to make person a new reference, a reference to a subpart of the original object.

So, at the last row of the first loop, `person = person[part]` (with part === 'person') actually makes `person` a reference to `originalPerson.person`.

Second run of loop: `part = name`, `person = originalObject.person.name`

`pathParts` now only have one part left, `last`. So at the last line in `update()`, `person.last = 'Doe'`. At that moment `person` is a reference to `originalPerson.name`, and `originalPerson` is updated accordingly.

The secret to understanding this snippet is that `person = person[part]` updates the reference to a "subobject" of `originalPerson` and then operates on that "subobject".